# Paypal CREATE type

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Here's an extended example flow that should work in the live environment:

- Send Pay request with actionType=CREATE
- Send SetPaymentOptions request using the returned payKey
- Redirect the user to approve the payment
- Receive IPN
- Send PaymentDetails request using the returned payKey
- Send GetPaymentOptions request using the returned payKey
- Send ExecutePayment request using the returned payKey

Everything works fine, till the last step. Somehow Payment is set to COMPLETED state as soon as the user approves the payment.

What am I doing wrong? I have used different card to accept the payment, and no paypal account so that I wouldn't be treated as the same user. Here are the details after user accepts the payment:

```
[status] => COMPLETED
[trackingId] => 
[payKey] => AP-XXXXXXXXX
[actionType] => CREATE
[feesPayer] => EACHRECEIVER
```

Comment: In my experience that is the intended result.  The only time ExecutePayment really comes into play is with delayed chained payments.

Comment: so how can I do the 'accept money only if there are still some items on the stock confirmed' in order to avoid all the  fees/ cancelations . preapproval?

Comment: Are you doing a split payment, or why exactly are you doing Adaptive Payments?  If you just use the Express Checkout API you can run it as an Authorization and then run DoCapture when you're ready to actually move the funds.

Comment: Yes I am doing split payment. But I will also look at Express checkout. thanks

Comment: Ok, well Express Checkout will accept parallel payments, but not chained, so depending on what exactly you're doing you may or may not be able to utilize EC.

Comment: I want manually to 'approve' the payment only after some of my scripts will finish the job. Also, I have to take some fees. So I am 'stuck' with PA (preapprovals). EC accepts parallel payments, but there is one big issue - all the receivers should have business account. The biggest issue with PA is that user has to have PayPal account.