# paypal actionType CREATE completes without ExecutePayment

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm using the adaptive payments API making a parallel payment with the actionType "CREATE". The buyer accepts the payment and is redirected to the returnUrl, but i see in my notifications that the transaction was complete without me calling "ExecutePayment".

I would like to capture the payment and Execute it within 48 hours, without any additional authorization from neither the buyer nor any of the receivers.

Similar issue (not resolved) here: [Adaptive Payments payment COMPLETED although actionType is CREATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155419/adaptive-payments-payment-completed-although-actiontype-is-create)

and here: 
[Paypal CREATE type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069785/paypal-create-type)

I also tried this: 
*Are you doing a split payment, or why exactly are you doing Adaptive Payments? If you just use the Express Checkout API you can run it as an Authorization and then run DoCapture when you're ready to actually move the funds.*

but the last step (DoCapture) doesn't allow me to transfer the amount to the second user.
error code:

```
Array
(
    [AUTHORIZATIONID] => O-0GJ340210A068152T
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2015-04-03T12:24:46Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => f4841861b9b5
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 74.0
    [BUILD] => 16057073
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10007
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Permission denied
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => You do not have permissions to make this API call
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
)
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

In short, Adaptive Payments doesn't support the notion of authorizing and capturing later.  Further, if the sender goes over to the PayPal website and approves the payment, the payment is going to complete immediately — regardless of what you set `actionType` to.  `actionType=CREATE` is primarily useful for implicit payments -- e.g., those payments where the API caller and the sender are the same party, or payments where you are using a preapproval that the sender has previously approved.